# How to Create Paging and Sorting for Custom Grid in C#

Tags: c#, gridview

I need to create my own grid which will have customized paging and sorting.

```
<MY:Grid id="grid" runat="server">
<columns>
Columns....
</Columns>
</MY:Grid>
```

I need to create the above grid such that customized paging and sorting is available whereever the grid is applied for entire application.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: And did you try googling this? We are here to help you, not write projects for you...

Comment: i googled it but  i did not get any thing related to override methods so i posted the question here

Comment: i need the custom grid to be used to override the paging and sorting

Comment: What custom grid are you talking about? Is it a third party control?

Comment: no thirdparty control use the existing gridview and override the methods for the paging and sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered a similar question here [How does pagination work in ASP.NET(Using VB.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789818/how-does-pagination-work-in-asp-netusing-vb-net/3789933#3789933). You should not enable built-in pagination and sorting of asp.net grid.

Your main task is to figure out the delta of your data that you need to display on your grid. Put your logic related to sorting and pagination in DB. Having the logic in DB reduces the network usage. Once you have desired dataset with you, you bind it to your grid. HTH.